# WPF Datagrid rows stretch to fill space with no scrollbars

Tags: wpf, xaml, blend

I'm having trouble getting my DataGrid to have the rows stretch to fill all available space, whenever the Window is at any size.  In this case, it should fill all space in the parent grid's second row (7*).  The DataGrid will always have 20 rows and 2 columns.  I never want any scrollbars to be shown.

I would like the DataGrid to look like this:

[image: Ideal]

However, if the Window is too short, items are truncated:

[image: Truncated]

If the Window is too tall, there is an ugly grey area at the bottom of the datagrid:

[image: Grey at bottom]

Here is the Xaml:

```
<UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:ignore="http://www.galasoft.ch/ignore"
    xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:WMT.ViewModel"
    xmlns:view="clr-namespace:WMT.View"
    xmlns:Design="clr-namespace:WMT.Design"
    xmlns:res="clr-namespace:WMT.Resources"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WMT"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
    xmlns:Custom="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"
    xmlns:debug="debug-mode"
    xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:Converters="clr-namespace:GTP.Contracts.Converters;assembly=GTP.Contracts"
    xmlns:Behaviours="clr-namespace:GTP.Contracts.Behaviours;assembly=GTP.Contracts"
    x:Class="WMT.View.FRView"
    mc:Ignorable="d mc"
    d:DesignWidth="706"
    d:DesignHeight="554" 
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type Design:DesignFRViewModel}, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
    >
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/WMT;component/Styles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <Converters:NegateConverter x:Key="NegateConverter"/>
        <System:Double x:Key="StandardWidth">240</System:Double>
        <Thickness x:Key="StandardMargin">0,0,10,0</Thickness>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
<UserControl.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/WMT;component/Images/cloud.bmp"/>
</UserControl.Background>

<Grid ShowGridLines="True">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.5*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="7*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="2.5*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding WmtResult.Responses}" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
              CanUserReorderColumns="False" 
              CanUserResizeColumns="False" 
              CanUserSortColumns="False" 
              GridLinesVisibility="None" 
              CanUserAddRows="False" 
              CanUserDeleteRows="False" 
              CanUserResizeRows="False" 
              RowHeaderWidth="0" 
              HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
              VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding IRPrompt.Item}" 
                                ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}"
                                Width="3*" 
                                Header="Word"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding FRPrompt}" 
                                ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" 
                                Width="*" 
                                Header="Count"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

I've tried a ListView instead of the DataGrid but had similar problems.  Do I need to use a Viewbox somewhere?  Let me know if you need further information.  Thanks.

**EDIT**

I'm trying Ryan Flohr's suggestion of placing the DataGrid inside a Viewbox.  This solves the truncation problem and the grey area below the DataGrid problem.  The DataGrid properly fills the space vertically, however it does not fill the space horizontally.

Here's the updated xaml:

```
<UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:ignore="http://www.galasoft.ch/ignore"
    xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:WMT.ViewModel"
    xmlns:view="clr-namespace:WMT.View"
    xmlns:Design="clr-namespace:WMT.Design"
    xmlns:res="clr-namespace:WMT.Resources"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WMT"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
    xmlns:Custom="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"
    xmlns:debug="debug-mode"
    xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:Converters="clr-namespace:GTP.Contracts.Converters;assembly=GTP.Contracts"
    xmlns:Behaviours="clr-namespace:GTP.Contracts.Behaviours;assembly=GTP.Contracts"
    x:Class="WMT.View.FRView"
    mc:Ignorable="d mc"
    d:DesignWidth="754"
    d:DesignHeight="685" 
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type Design:DesignFRViewModel}, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
    >
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/WMT;component/Styles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <Converters:NegateConverter x:Key="NegateConverter"/>
        <System:Double x:Key="StandardWidth">240</System:Double>
        <Thickness x:Key="StandardMargin">0,0,10,0</Thickness>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
<UserControl.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/WMT;component/Images/cloud.bmp"/>
</UserControl.Background>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.5*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="7*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="2.5*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Viewbox Grid.Row="1">
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding WmtResult.Responses}" 
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                  CanUserReorderColumns="False" 
                  CanUserResizeColumns="False" 
                  CanUserSortColumns="False" 
                  GridLinesVisibility="None" 
                  CanUserAddRows="False" 
                  CanUserDeleteRows="False" 
                  CanUserResizeRows="False" 
                  RowHeaderWidth="0" 
                  VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding IRPrompt.Item}" 
                                    ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" 
                                    Header="Word"
                                    >
                    <!--<DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,190,0" />
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>-->
                </DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding FRPrompt}" 
                                    ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" 
                                    Header="Count">
                    <!--<DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,60,0" />
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>-->
                </DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Viewbox>

</Grid>
```

Here's a screenshot:

[image: Viewbox No Margin]

I tried playing with the HorizontalAlignment and HorizontalContentAlignment of the DataGrid, but had no luck.  I then changed the margin of the Columns (see commented section of the xaml), but can only get the proper margin when the Window is a certain size.  Here's screenshots when I have the margin set to an exact value (see the commented CellStyle sections in the xaml):

[image: ViewboxMarginTooSkinny]
[image: ViewboxMarginTooShort]

I suppose I might be able to use a ValueConverter to bind the Margin to a percentage of the Viewbox's actual width, however this seems quite hacky.

Is there a way to replace the internal StackPanel of the DataGrid with some sort of layout control that will fill the space horizontally?  The 1st column should be 3 times as wide as the 2nd column.

Comment: Change the Row it's in Height to `Auto`

Comment: What if the window is too short to show only 2 rows ?

Comment: I'm trying to understand what results you expect. Are you saying you want all 20 rows to show even if the the window is too small, and not show any scrollbars?

Comment: @RyanFlohr Yes I always want all 20 rows to show no matter what size the Window is.  The Window will always be maximized so it will never be too short to only show a few rows.  I never want any scrollbars in either direction.  The DataGrid should fill all space vertically and horizontally (within the 1st column and the 7* row of the parent grid)

Comment: @AnjumSKhan The Window will always be maximized so it will never be too short to only show a few rows.

Comment: @ChrisW. I don't believe you can set a DataGrid's Row Height to Auto

Comment: Use a ViewBox. It should give you the results you expect.

Comment: @JohnnyHerms The parent grid the DataGrid sits in, not the DataGrid itself. Your layout dictates structure top down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to achieve the desired result by using a Viewbox around the DataGrid with Stretch set to Fill.  I also had to set a Height and a Width on the DataGrid in order to give it an aspect ratio that is preserved when the Window size is changed.  Here's the xaml:

```
<UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:ignore="http://www.galasoft.ch/ignore"
    xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:WMT.ViewModel"
    xmlns:view="clr-namespace:WMT.View"
    xmlns:Design="clr-namespace:WMT.Design"
    xmlns:res="clr-namespace:WMT.Resources"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WMT"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
    xmlns:Custom="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"
    xmlns:debug="debug-mode"
    xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:Converters="clr-namespace:GTP.Contracts.Converters;assembly=GTP.Contracts"
    xmlns:Behaviours="clr-namespace:GTP.Contracts.Behaviours;assembly=GTP.Contracts"
    x:Class="WMT.View.FRView"
    mc:Ignorable="d mc"
    d:DesignWidth="688"
    d:DesignHeight="554" 
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type Design:DesignFRViewModel}, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
    >
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/WMT;component/Styles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <Converters:NegateConverter x:Key="NegateConverter"/>
        <System:Double x:Key="StandardWidth">240</System:Double>
        <Thickness x:Key="StandardMargin">0,0,10,0</Thickness>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
<UserControl.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/WMT;component/Images/cloud.bmp"/>
</UserControl.Background>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.5*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="7*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="2.5*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Viewbox Grid.Row="1" Stretch="Fill">
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="1"
                  Background="White"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding WmtResult.Responses}" 
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                  CanUserReorderColumns="False" 
                  CanUserResizeColumns="False" 
                  CanUserSortColumns="False" 
                  GridLinesVisibility="None" 
                  CanUserAddRows="False" 
                  CanUserDeleteRows="False" 
                  CanUserResizeRows="False" 
                  RowHeaderWidth="0" 
                  VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                  ColumnWidth="*"
                  IsReadOnly="True"
                  Height="385" Width="300">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding IRPrompt.Item}" 
                                    ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" 
                                    Header="Word"
                                    Width="2*"
                                    >
                </DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding FRPrompt}" 
                                    ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" 
                                    Header="Count"
                                    Width="*">
                  </DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Viewbox>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want all twenty rows to appear, even if the window is sized too small, while at the same time not showing any vertical scrollbars, you will have to put the DataGrid in a ViewBox. This will also ensure that "ugly gray" doesn't get shown.

Internally in the DataGrid control, the content itself is inside of a StackPanel, which will grow to whatever the space the content itself requires. That StackPanel is inside of a ScrollViewer, so that if the content grows too large for the Window, you can scroll it. Since you've disabled the scrollbar capability, it is essentially just a StackPanel that will continue to grow. Since you've set explicit size limitations on the Grid, the DataGrid is only going to show the portion of the DataGrid that its size allows, making the content appear to be truncated. On the other hand if the grid grows much larger than the internal content in the StackPanel, the StackPanel sizes to the grid, but its content stops where it stops. That "ugly" gray color your are seeing is the background color of the control.